# Exiting from a function that has a local std::thread object without join

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I have the following simple function, just for demonstration:

```
void thread_func(int i) {
    return i;
}
```

And I have another function that calls it in a new thread and does not wait for it to return:

```
void my_nice_function() {
    std::thread t(thread_func, 15);
}
```

Since `t` is a local variable in `my_nice_function()`, I am concerned that when `my_nice_function()` exits, `t` will be destroyed while running.

Is there a reason to be concerned?
How can I let the thread `t` run in background even after returning from `my_nice_function()`?

Comment: You must call `join()` or `detach()` on `t` before it's destroyed, otherwise `~thread` destructor calls `terminate()` and therefore aborts the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use std::thread::detach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate since not everybody know what `std::detach` is. Using `std::detach` seems to be the answer here

Comment: @SomethingSomething, The link explains what `detach` does. People with this problem have their question answered by the link.

Comment: The answer for my question is not the answer for what `detach()` does, but is that I should use `detach()` - a function that I haven't known before and possibly also other developers don't. I agree that pointing to there as an answer and telling "use detach() and read that post" is fine, but it is not a duplicate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concern is valid. Reading suitable [reference documentation for `std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) tells us that on destruction:

> If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called.

So destroying `t` without either detaching or joining it will end your program.

You therefore have two options, depending on what you want to happen. If you want the function to wait for the thread to finish, call `t.join()` before returning. If you instead want the thread to keep running after the function returns, call `t.detach()`.

Comment: So the solution for my case is to add `t.detach()` after creating `t`, right? (Given that I don't want to wait for the thread to finish, but I do want it to run in the background)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a reason of concern. The code will not work as intended. You can either do

```
t.join ()
```

This should be written if you want your main function to wait till execution of the threaded func. is completed.
Or

```
t.detach ()
```

This should be called if you want the threaded func. to run independently, i mean main func. should not wait for it complete.

You can also use Sleep (x). If you want the function to run for x seconds only.
Calling terminate() is generally not recommended as it kills all threads including main () thread. There is no need to kill a thread. When the finction running in a thread completes the threads automatically cleans itself up.

Refer to this: [How to Destroy a thread object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46827203/8619231)